# AJAX запрос фильтрации возвращает все результаты

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, ajax

Делаю запрос на сервер и отправляю к нему **name** объекта, который содержит в себе название категории по которой фильтрую, в function.php принимаю через **$_POST['name']** значение и дальше код

```
if(isset($name)){
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'cars',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'class',
            'value' => $name
        )
    );
    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $result-> have_posts()) : 
     while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
     <div class="history" style="">
     <img style="width: 120px" src="<?php the_field('car_img'); ?>"/>
     <p style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 16px; line-height: 21.7px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 58px;"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
     <?php the_field('характеристики'); ?>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
}
```

но он возвращает даже те результаты которые не совпадают с $name

Comment: У Вас запись `meta_query` не верная. Должно быть `'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'class', 'value' => $name))`

Comment: @Simon спасибо, твой совет помог